# Submit week number with datepicker Jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker, submit, week-number

i'd like to know if it's possible to submit the week number in addition with the date using a datepicker jQuery ?

for example :2014/08/23 for the first field (visible) witch is what i already have ,  and [week] 34 for the second field (hidden).

Here is the french version of the datepicker i'm supposed to use :

```
(function(factory) {
if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {

    define(["../datepicker"], factory);
} else {

    factory(jQuery.datepicker);
}
}(function(datepicker) {
datepicker.regional['fr'] = {
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    minDate: +2, maxDate: "+21D",
    showButtonPanel: true,
    closeText: 'Fermer',
    prevText: 'Précédent',
    nextText: 'Suivant',
    currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
    monthNames: ['janvier', 'février', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin',
        'juillet', 'août', 'septembre', 'octobre', 'novembre', 'décembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['janv.', 'févr.', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin',
        'juil.', 'août', 'sept.', 'oct.', 'nov.', 'déc.'],
    dayNames: ['dimanche', 'lundi', 'mardi', 'mercredi', 'jeudi', 'vendredi',          'samedi'],
    dayNamesShort: ['dim.', 'lun.', 'mar.', 'mer.', 'jeu.', 'ven.', 'sam.'],
    dayNamesMin: ['D', 'L', 'M', 'M', 'J', 'V', 'S'],
    weekHeader: 'Semaine',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    showWeek: true,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: ''};
datepicker.setDefaults(datepicker.regional['fr']);
return datepicker.regional['fr'];
}));
```

and this how i use it in my form :

```
 <form action="index.php?page=3 " name="formCmdRep" method="POST">
    <div class="menu-block">
    <div class="presMenu">

        <?php include 'formPart2.php'; ?>       
    </div>   
    <div class="presMenu">
        <p>commande du : <input name="commandeDu:"type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
        <?php include 'formPart1.php'; ?>

    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

i've tried to turn showMonthAfterYear to true, and it doesn't change anything.
I also naïvely tried to change the dateFormat , like dd/mm/yy/ww but it seems ww doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the week number using the datepicker's `onSelect`-event and `iso8601Week`-function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtDate').datepicker({
       showWeek: true,
       firstDay: 1,
       onSelect: function(dateText) {        
           $("#txtWeek").val($.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)));
           $("#selectedDate").val(dateText);
       }
    });
});
```

Working demo: [Datepicker week number and date](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/nhLzu28e/)